# Linker error when building extension "no such file or directory: '_NSExtensionMain'"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, clang

I've inherited an older project with lots of dependencies that had some problems getting a solid build through CI. After close inspection the `master` branch simply was broken and I had some fixing to do. I could get it to work pretty quick except for the extension. When removing the extension the projects builds and runs. There was also a `dev` branch that still worked out of the box but was outdated. I've compared the differences and it seems to boil down to a subtle change in the linker. As soon as I copied the working linker command from the `dev` branch on the `master` branch it would pass and vice versa.

## Differences

There were more differences than these two lines, but I tried swapping them all out and there was no difference in result.

### Working version (dev branch)

```
 -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -fapplication-extension -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -L/usr/lib/swift
 -Xlinker -add_ast_path
 -Xlinker /Users/[me]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[App]-cjrxbriquvbkmcgdurzwekbylpik/Build/Intermediates.noindex/[App].build/Debug-iphonesimulator/[App]-PrintAction.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/[App]_PrintAction.swiftmodule -e _NSExtensionMain
```

### Failing version (master branch)

```
 -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -fapplication-extension -B -e _NSExtensionMain
```

## Question

I don't know why these two lines are different or what the reason is there seems to be a part missing in the `master` version. I could find no differences in flags but I might have been looking in the wrong place.

## Full version

Pretty formatted:

```
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
     -target x86_64-apple-ios12.1-simulator <-- Beide
     -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.6.sdk 
     -L/Users/[me]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[App]-cjrxbriquvbkmcgdurzwekbylpik/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator 
     -F/Users/[me]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[App]-cjrxbriquvbkmcgdurzwekbylpik/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator 
     -filelist /Users/[me]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[App]-cjrxbriquvbkmcgdurzwekbylpik/Build/Intermediates.noindex/[App].build/Debug-iphonesimulator/[App]-PrintAction.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/[App]-PrintAction.LinkFileList 
     -Xlinker -rpath 
     -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks 
     -Xlinker -rpath 
     -Xlinker @executable_path/../../Frameworks -dead_strip 
     -Xlinker -object_path_lto 
     -Xlinker /Users/[me]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[App]-cjrxbriquvbkmcgdurzwekbylpik/Build/Intermediates.noindex/[App].build/Debug-iphonesimulator/[App]-PrintAction.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/[App]-PrintAction_lto.o 
     -Xlinker -export_dynamic 
     -Xlinker -no_deduplicate 
     -Xlinker -objc_abi_version 
     -Xlinker 2 
     -fobjc-arc 
     -fobjc-link-runtime 
     -fapplication-extension 
     -B 
     -e _NSExtensionMain
     -Xlinker -sectcreate 
     -Xlinker __TEXT 
     -Xlinker __entitlements 
     -Xlinker /Users/[me]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[App]-cjrxbriquvbkmcgdurzwekbylpik/Build/Intermediates.noindex/[App].build/Debug-iphonesimulator/[App]-PrintAction.build/[App]-PrintAction.appex-Simulated.xcent 
     -framework SystemConfiguration 
     -framework MobileCoreServices 
     -framework [App]Core 
     -lPods-[App]-PrintAction 
     -Xlinker -dependency_info 
     -Xlinker /Users/[me]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[App]-cjrxbriquvbkmcgdurzwekbylpik/Build/Intermediates.noindex/[App].build/Debug-iphonesimulator/[App]-PrintAction.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/[App]-PrintAction_dependency_info.dat 
     -o /Users/[me]/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/[App]-cjrxbriquvbkmcgdurzwekbylpik/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/[App]-PrintAction.appex/[App]-PrintAction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-B` flag was the culprit, it was added somewhere in the build settings for reasons unknown. I think the "no such file or directory" error usually is caused by some kind of foreign flag that makes the linker think you're giving a file argument instead of the value part of some kind of flag.